# Prompting "ImportError: No module named py27_urlquote" when running dev_appserver.py on Google Cloud SDK

Tags: python, macos, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sdk

When I run dev_appserver.py on google-cloud-sdk, I get ImportError: No module named py27_urlquote.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 109, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 103, in _run_file
    _execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 83, in _execfile
    execfile(fn, scope)
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 44, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import dispatcher
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import module
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 39, in <module>
    import py27_urlquote
ImportError: No module named py27_urlquote
```

I have tried the following:

1. Reinstall Cloud SDK
2. Find out about the py27_urlquote module (I couldn't find any such information ...)
3. Change the version of CLOUDSDK_PYTHON to 2.7 or 3.8 and execute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now this is a public issue and is currently being addressed by our Google Engineering Team. A workaround was provided for you to run your local development server:

1. Install `pip` for Python 2

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python-pip
```

2. Install `urlquote` instead of `py27_urlquote`

```
pip install urlquote
```

3. Modify `module.py` located on your local directory from the error message

```
/Users/user/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py
```

4. Replace `py27_urlquote` to `urlquote`. There are 3 lines of code that uses `py27_urlquote`. Specifically lines 39, 833, and 836.

You can check this [public tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/200817325) similar to your issue for more information and updates.

Comment: It seems that the equivalent call in urlquote is not `urlquote` but `quote`: https://pypi.org/project/urlquote/ .

To make it work I've replaced the import with `from urlquote import quote` and the other two lines from `py27_urlquote.urlquote(...` to `quote(...`

Comment: Step 2 may need to be `pip2 install urlquote`

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered this problem too on the SDK version 359.0.0

Instead of updating the SDK files manually, I opted for downgrading to a previous version.

I found that version 357.0.0 works fine.

To downgrade, run the following command:

```
gcloud components update --version 357.0.0
```